# Stop Video Playing after playing in FancyBox

Tags: youtube, fancybox

Just a quick question on this and how I can get a youtube video to stop playing when exiting a modal.

We have this homepage slider > https://www.bababing.com/

You can see that when you click on a tile in the slider it opens and starts playing the video. However, when you exit it still plays the video.

Is there anyway we can stop his happening that anyone knows of?

We are using fancy box to open the lightbox area.

Upon the video opening I also want it to autoplay the videos

Any thoughts would be fantastic

Thanks,
Glen

Answer (score 0):

You have youtube player code inside inline content, but the script literally moves your content into the modal and puts back after closing. Therefore, if user interacts with your content, it stays the same after closing the modal.

You have several options:

1) You could use Youtube API to stop/start videos after content is displayed/hidden;

2) Display cloned version of your content (e.g., something like `$.fancybox.open( $('my-element').clone(true) );` ), but then you probably still would need to use Youtube API to start video;

3) Build your own content on click event - something like `$.fancybox.open( 'there will be youtube iframe code with autoplay option and something more' );` - this way you will avoid messing with Youtube API

4) Use direct links to Youtube like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sI_Ps7JSEk&amp;autoplay=1` - the script will then parse it and load inside iframe automatically

Comment: Thanks Janis. Could you provide a simple example from what you can see publicly? The simplest example...